# NullPointer Cursor with SQLiteOpenHelper in android

Tags: android, cursor

After creating the table with `pm.createTable()` and adding data to it using `pm.addDataToTable()`, I am trying to retrieve the data using `pm.getData()` of the same table, that i just created and inserted, and store it in cursor c. I am not getting any compilation errors or exceptions. The control always enters the else condition in `displayData()`. Can someone help me with this?

```
PortfolioManager pm;
Cursor c, cMainTable; 

pm = new PortfolioManager(this);        
cMainTable = pm.getData("mainTable");

scriptName = edtxtScriptName.getText().toString();


   try
                {
                System.out.println("Creating table with name "+scriptName);
                pm.createTable(scriptName);
                System.out.println("Table created");
                pm.addDataToTable(scriptName, DOP, purchasedQuantity, purchasedPrice, brokerage, serviceTax, stt, stampDuty);
                System.out.println("data added");

                c = pm.getData(scriptName);
                displayData(c);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println("Exception at try catch block");
                }

    private void displayData(Cursor c2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(c2 != null) // Should enter this statement. Always enters else condition
            {                   
                if(c2.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    c2.moveToFirst();

                    do
                    {

                        // obtain data from cursor

                    }while(c2.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Cursor c2 is Empty");
            }

        }
```

portfoliomanager.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class PortfolioManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    static String name = "portfolio";
    static int version = 1;

    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
    Cursor c;

    public PortfolioManager(Context context) {
        super(context, name, null, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        sqlDB = getWritableDatabase();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sqlDB.execSQL("create table if not exists maintable(scriptnumber text, scriptname text, totalquantity int, " +
                "averageprice double, lossorgain double)");

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public Cursor getData(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String table = string;

        sqlDB.rawQuery("select * from "+table, null);       
        return c;
    }
    public void addDataToTable(String scriptName, String dOP, int purchasedQuantity, double purchasedPrice, 
            double brokerage, double serviceTax, double stt, double stampDuty) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        sqlDB.execSQL("insert into "+scriptName+" values('"+dOP+"', '"+purchasedQuantity+"', '"+purchasedPrice+"'," +
                "'"+brokerage+"', '"+serviceTax+"', '"+stt+"', '"+stampDuty+"')");
    }
    public void createTable(String scriptName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sqlDB.execSQL("create table if not exists "+scriptName+"(dateofpurchase text, purchasedquantity int, purchasedprice double," +
                " brokerage double, servicetax double, stt double, stampduty double)");

    }



}
```

Output :::

```
01-17 23:38:16.799: I/System.out(23248): Creating table with name nal
01-17 23:38:16.869: I/System.out(23248): Table created
01-17 23:38:16.929: I/System.out(23248): data added
01-17 23:38:16.929: I/System.out(23248): Cursor c2 is Empty
```

Comment: have u check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not Assign value of **cursor** in this method `getData(String string);`

I think your `getData(String string)` method should be like this instead of old one:

```
public Cursor getData(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Curser c= null;
        String table = string;

       c = sqlDB.rawQuery("select * from "+table, null);   

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah.. got it sorted by Sam's answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you need to use the Cursor returned by `rawQuery()`. Change this:

```
public Cursor getData(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String table = string;

    sqlDB.rawQuery("select * from "+table, null);       
    return c;
}
```

To something like:

```
public Cursor getData(String table) {
    return sqlDB.rawQuery("select * from "+table, null);       
}
```

---

Also the logic in your if-else block isn't quite right. Unless `rawQuery()` throws an exception it will always return a Cursor, so it may be *empty* but it probably won't be null. Try:

```
if(c2 != null) // Should enter this statement. Always enters else condition
{                   
    if(c2.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while(c2.moveToNext());
            // read data
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Cursor c2 is Empty");
    }
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Somethings gone horribly wrong");
}
```

Comment: Do you plan on using `c` anywhere else in your PortfolioManager? If not, there is no reason to retain a reference to `c`.